# Regular Expression Letter followed by numbers or numbers and a letter

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am having some difficulty with the following for a regular expression:

G followed by 1-5 numbers

or G followed by 4 numbers followed by a single letter A-Z

Could someone please assist?

e.g. of valid entries would be:

```
G2
G12
G123
G1234
G12345
G1234A
```

Thanks

Comment: `G(\d{1,5}|\d{4}[A-Z])` covers all your test cases.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
^[G][0-9]{1,5}?$|^[G][0-9]{4}[A-Z]?$
```

`^[G]` means starts with G
`[0-9]{1,5}` means next 1 to 5 letters are numeric
`[0-9]{4}` means next 4 letters are numeric 
`[A-Z]` means last character must be a letter between A -Z.

[image: Test results]

Comment: this will work  if  the given examples strings are entered in separated lines not the same line

Comment: yes i just need to match individual strings against it

Comment: You don't need the `?` in `{1,5}?` (lazy) and the `?` in `[A-Z]?` (optional).

Answer (score 3):

Try this Regex

```
^\b[G][0-9]{1,5}?$|^[G][0-9]{4}[A-Z]?$
```

## [REGEX DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/KHXEtw1HQH)

OP:

[image]

Regex Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [G]                      any character of: 'G'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{1,5}?              any character of: '0' to '9' (between 1
                           and 5 times (matching the least amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [G]                      any character of: 'G'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{4}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (4 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z]?                   any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: You are adding all sorts of redundancy into your regex. `^G[0-9]{1,5}$|^G[0-9]{4}[A-Z]$` should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :-

```
  G\d{4}[A-Z]|G\d{1,5}
```

Comment: `G` is redundant, and can be removed from the conditional.

Comment: It also matches G125A which has two few digits