# How to match exact combinations of letters and numbers, within known lengths?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a C# application that imports customer data, and I'm finding one use case to be challenging. First, here are some examples of strings:

`Z20Q`

`M20A1070A20T`

`M20A1070D03D0480A20B`

I need a c# regex to extract either of the following patterns, as often as they are found, where `L`=Letter and `N`=Number:

`LNNL` or `LNNLNNNN`

You can count on the following:

1. Patterns cannot overlap. Once a match is found, extract that segment, and only look at any remaining string that has not yet matched.
2. Every character of a string will match - no character(s) will ever be discarded.
3. Must attempt to match `LNNLNNNN` before attempting to match `LNNL`. If `LNNLNNNN` is matched, extract it and continue attempting to match whatever remains of the string.
4. The lengths and locations of those patterns are precise, and can be counted on. But as you can see from my example strings, the lengths of strings can vary.
5. Each extracted/matched string must be exactly 4 characters or exactly 8 characters.
6. The character count of each string will be an exact multiple of 4: 4, 8, 12, 16, 20 (I don't think there can ever be more than 20)
7. Strings will consist entirely of alphanumeric characters - no spaces or special characters - just letters and numbers

So let's step through a few:

> `Z20Q` - we're done - if it's 4 characters I don't need regex, I can
>   grab it and go.
>
> `M20A1070A20T` should produce and extract 2 strings: `M20A1070` (matches
>   pattern `LNNLNNNN`) and `A20T` (matches pattern `LNNL`)
>
> `M20A1070D03D0480A20B` should produce and extract 3 strings: `M20A1070`
>   (matches pattern `LNNLNNNN`) and `D03D0480` (matches pattern `LNNLNNNN`) and
>   `A20B` (matches pattern `LNNL`)

I have been studying [this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575028/regular-expression-letter-followed-by-numbers-or-numbers-and-a-letter/21575427), looking at `^[G][0-9]{1,5}?$|^[G][0-9]{4}[A-Z]?$` - which seems like a promising start, but my regex kung fu is weak and I would greatly appreciate some advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
var input = "M20A1070D03D0480A20B";
var regex = new Regex("[A-Z][0-9]{2}[A-Z]([0-9]{4})?");

foreach(var match in regex.Matches(input).Cast<Match>().Select(x=>x.Value))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

Output:

> M20A1070
>   D03D0480
>   A20B

The regex basically says match the main pattern and then optionally match four digits as well. Because Regex is greedy it will always take the four extra numbers if they exist.

Of note is that this currently assumes capital letters only (as in your example). If you need case insensitive searching you'll need to modify it slightly.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: Ah. I did just comment above (now deleted) wondering if I'd missed something. I guess it was you that missed something. :)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you Chris!